# 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data != null' A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: flutter

Hi can some help me with this error everytime I click the notification details on my flutter app it goes red with this error message.

please someome help me cant find solutions here

Update: I am not 100% sure if this is the right code that cossing the issues

```
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.close),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
          ),
        ),

        Container(
          height: 150, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_LARGE),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.RADIUS_SMALL), color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.20)),
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.RADIUS_SMALL),
            child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
              placeholder: Images.placeholder,
              image: '${Get.find<SplashController>().configModel.baseUrls.notificationImageUrl}/${notificationModel.image}',
              height: 150, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, fit: BoxFit.cover,
              imageErrorBuilder: (c, o, s) => Image.asset(
                Images.placeholder, height: 150,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_LARGE),

        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_LARGE),
          child: Text(
            notificationModel.title,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: robotoMedium.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: Dimensions.FONT_SIZE_LARGE),
              ),
        ),

        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 20),
          child: Text(
            notificationModel.description,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: robotoRegular.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).disabledColor),
          ),
        ),

      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

when I update the code to  Text(someVariable ?? 'Default text if varible is null')
[mobile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp8jk.jpg)

my text.dart error location

```
 assert(
      data != null,
     'A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.',
   ),
   textSpan = null,
   super(key: key);
```

Comment: You are using a `Text` widget somewhere which takes some variable whose value is `null`.

Comment: add some code so that we can see what you are doing and what the problem may be.

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply where can I possibly get the codes that are related to this problem is it on the main.dart file?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have Text widget where you are passing variable with the text, which in this case is null.
So basically you need to check that variable before using it in Text widget.

You can check null safe like:

```
Text(someVariable ?? 'Default text if varible is null')
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response I am totally newbie with this can you please tell me where can I lcoate this lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can use elves operator..
the below code is part of your code

```
Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_LARGE),
          child: Text(
            notificationModel.title ?? "Text value is null",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: robotoMedium.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor, fontSize: Dimensions.FONT_SIZE_LARGE),
              ),
        ),
```

Comment: Hi yes it fix the error but right now may notification has only a image holder and a text (text value is null) under it?

it supposed to be a order notification

Comment: get control why is the notificationModel.title empty? may your database controller  has error

Comment: if ever that is the issue can I know how to fix it?

Comment: actually of course, use print("$notificationModel.title") function in the data post(to save database) function, to print output in the console.  if output null when complete your database post function, so your post function is incorrect or check datatable in the your database

Comment: thank you so much for the info.. will do this one.